# Spark packages flag vs jars dir?

Tags: apache-spark

In Spark, what's the difference between adding JARs to the classpath via `--packages` argument and just adding the JARs directly to the `$SPARK_HOME/jars` directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** `jars` are used for local or remote jar files specified with URL and dont resolve dependencies, `packages` are used for Maven coordinates, and do resolve dependencies. [From docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management)

- `--jars`

  > When using spark-submit, the application jar along with any jars included with the --jars option will be automatically transferred to the cluster. URLs supplied after --jars must be separated by commas. That list is included in the driver and executor classpaths. Directory expansion does not work with --jars.
- `--packages`

  > Users may also include any other dependencies by supplying a comma-delimited list of Maven coordinates with --packages. All transitive dependencies will be handled when using this command. Additional repositories (or resolvers in SBT) can be added in a comma-delimited fashion with the flag --repositories. (Note that credentials for password-protected repositories can be supplied in some cases in the repository URI, such as in https://user:password@host/.... Be careful when supplying credentials this way.) These commands can be used with pyspark, spark-shell, and spark-submit to include Spark Packages.

Comment: Thanks @user9789292 (+1) -- but I'm not talking about the `--jars` flag, I'm talking about placing the JAR files in `$SPARK_HOME/jars` directory vs `--packages`. Any ideas?